# Monitoring WSO2 Message Broker via JMX

Tags: wso2

I've been attempting to monitor the WSO2 MB 2.1.1 via JMX which appears to be a valid option for other WSO2 tools such as the ESB however the MB does not appear to be updating any of the MBeans for the Queue attributes.

Ex:

```
org.wso2.andes:type=VirtualHost.Queue,VirtualHost="carbon",name="testQueue"
```

This has a number of potentially useful attributes like the following:

```
ConsumerCount
ActiveConsumerCount
ReceivedMessageCount
MessageCount
```

However the counters always read "0" even when there are messages in the queue dropped in via the sample sender or manually.

Creating a new queue will create the following, but the issue is seen on the new queue as well.

```
org.wso2.andes:type=VirtualHost.Queue,VirtualHost="carbon",name="testQueue2"
```

Am I simply looking in the incorrect location or any other variety of user error?

Is this the intentional behavior of the application?

Do you have any suggestions which may assist in getting this data reported via JMX?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be functional in MB 2.1.1, it looks as if they may be moving to using the CEP or the BAM to provide metrics on some products.